# Snowflake defaults searches in public schema even if actual schema doesnot exist

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

I am using snowflake jdbc, while querying for a table in an invalid schema name, Snowflake still tries to search it in public schema. Is it snowflake's default behaviour? Can I override/change it and throw exception if not found in input schema name ?

For example, I am trying:

```
select * 
from mydb.test_schema_invalid.table_1;
```

This schema is not present in my database, but this table is present in public schema, so snowflake is still giving me results for this

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue.  Are you actually querying the fully qualified table name, or are you trying to connect to a database and schema in the connection string and then querying the unqualified table name?

Comment: If the table name is provided as unquallified name `select * from table_1` then checking the [SEARCH_PATH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/name-resolution.html#queries) `"The default value of the search path is $current, $public."` should be the next step.

Comment: ok. Can I remove $public from the search path and only have $current ?

Comment: @anurag1007 1) If you really need to have schema tied object then I suggest using qualified name `SELECT * FROM schema.table_name` this way you are very explicit which object is accessed. 2) As per documentation search path "The search path is stored in the session-level parameter SEARCH_PATH. Similar to any other parameter, it can be changed using the ALTER SESSION command." so it could be altered with ALTER SESSION SET SEARCH_PATH = '$current' each time a new session is established

Comment: got it. I am better trying to give fully qualified name. Thanks